# Improve Linq Perfomance with Join

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq

I have a Linq and its taking time so long like 2-3 minutes to get 8000 data.
is there anybody can help me to improve my Linq for this process.

```
var listOP = (from f in db.T_COLLECT_OP_DTL.Where
                                (x => x.PRODUCTION_DATE == prodDate && (x.SHIFT == shifts || x.SHIFT == shift))
                      from g in db.T_COLLECT_OP_DTL_KIMPER.Where
                                (x => x.PTDHCARD_ID == f.PTDHCARD_ID &&
                                (x.PRODUCTION_DATE == f.PRODUCTION_DATE) &&
                                (x.SHIFT == f.SHIFT) &&
                                 x.KIMPER_ID ==
                                 db.T_COLLECT_OP_DTL_KIMPER.Where
                                (y => y.PTDHCARD_ID == x.PTDHCARD_ID && y.MODEL == x.MODEL &&
                                 y.PRODUCTION_DATE == x.PRODUCTION_DATE &&
                                 y.SHIFT == x.SHIFT)
                                 .Max(y => y.KIMPER_ID)) 
                      from ii in db.T_SETUP_UNIT.Where
                                (x => x.PRODUCTION_DATE == fsu && (x.SHIFT == fsh) && x.CURRENT_DELAY != "Breakdown")
                      join h in db.M_PRODUCT_MODEL on g.MODEL equals h.MODEL_CODE
                      from i in db.M_EQUIPMENT.Where
                      (x => x.EQUIPMENT_ID == ii.EQUIPMENT_ID && x.PRODUCT_MODEL_ID == h.PRODUCT_MODEL_ID)
                      select new
                      {
                          f.OPERATOR_ID,
                          f.PRODUCTION_DATE,
                          f.SHIFT,
                          g.MODEL,
                          g.KIMPER_ID,
                          g.EXP_UNIT,
                          i.UNIT_NO
                      }).ToList();
```

Comment: What (related) tables/indices do you have?

Comment: Use SQL instead of the garbage linq spews out

Comment: that would be nice if you give another solution, thanks  @Mardoxx

Comment: @fadil adam The only realistic answer is **don't**. Queries like these are bugs in themselves and a very strong indication (think billowing smoke) that the entity model/context configuration is wrong. Either use a SQL query or proper navigation properties between entities. LINQ isn't a replacement for SQL and EF is an ORM, not a database driver. It's EF's job to construct the proper joins from your relations, navigation properties

Comment: @fadiladam and no, there is no other solution. 2 minutes for no data at all is atrocious. Processing 8K records should take less than 2 seconds. The query itself is incomprehensible. Even if you wrote SQL, it would be a very bad query. Once you clean up the query and remove clear problems like scanning entire tables multiple times, you should check the execution plan and add any missing indexes

Comment: His request is doing useless process, it might be better with the solution I suggested. However, navigation through properties is better, and Entityframework is designed for such a thing. reference : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Ir4EIqxYXQ

Comment: I have to echo the calls to do this in SQL. Ultimately, LINQ generators are pretty simplistic and formulaic, and any competently written custom SQL will usually be *at least as good* as the generated SQL, usually much better. But: if you're writing it by hand, you can play with the query, look at the SQL execution plan, etc - to tune it. And if it turns out you need to tweak the DDL (not just the DML) to fix it: you can

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that :

```
var listOP = (from f in db.T_COLLECT_OP_DTL
              from ii in db.T_SETUP_UNIT
              join g in db.T_COLLECT_OP_DTL_KIMPER on new { A = f.PTDHCARD_ID, B f.PRODUCTION_DATE, C = f.SHIFT } equals new { A = g.PTDHCARD_ID, B = g.PRODUCTION_DATE, C = g.SHIFT}
              join h in db.M_PRODUCT_MODEL on g.MODEL equals h.MODEL_CODE
              join i in db.M_EQUIPMENT on new {A = ii.EQUIPMENT_ID, B = h.PRODUCT_MODEL_ID} equals new {A = i.EQUIPMENT_ID, B = i.PRODUCT_MODEL_ID}
              let kimperid = (from codk in g
                              select codk.KIMPER_ID).Max()
              where f.PRODUCTION_DATE == prodDate 
              && ( (f.SHIFT == shifts || f.SHIFT == shift) )
              && ii.PRODUCTION_DATE == fsu
              && ii.SHIFT == fsh
              && ii.CURRENT_DELAY != "Breakdown"
              select new
                      {
                          f.OPERATOR_ID,
                          f.PRODUCTION_DATE,
                          f.SHIFT,
                          g.MODEL,
                          g.KIMPER_ID,
                          g.EXP_UNIT,
                          i.UNIT_NO
                      }).ToList();
```